# Is there a simpler way of copying and pasting one inputs value into other input with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write something that will copy the current `<input>`s value and enter it into any `<input>` that start with the same name.

`<input>` names will follow this pattern: `price-0`, `price-1`, `price-2`, `upc-0`, `upc-1`, `upc-2`.

So if a user enters a value in `<input name="price-0">` and hits copy the value should be transferred over to all input whos name start with `price`

This is the code I've written:

```
$(document).on('click', '.--copy', function () {
    var input_name = $(this).closest('div').find('input').attr('name').split('-')[0];
    $('input[name^=' + input_name + ']').val($(this).closest('div').find('input').val());
});
```

A fiddle to make everyones life easier: http://jsfiddle.net/6jGLD/

I feel like there are too many selectors being called upon and the code is somewhat difficult to read.

Comment: It would probably be easier to give each related input an identical class. Other than that, I would do `$input = $(this).closest('div').find('input')` at the beginning of your function so you don't have to traverse the dom to find the input twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One minor improvement I can think of is to create a variable to hold the input element since the element is used twice like

```
$(document).on('click', '.--copy', function () {
    var $input = $(this).closest('div').find('input'), input_name = $input.attr('name').split('-')[0];
    $('input[name^=' + input_name + ']').val($input.val());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z4FUd/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just grab the value of the first input put it in a variable and put that variable as the value of the second input for example

```
var value = $('input.firstInput').val();
            $('input.secondInput').val(value);
```

here is a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/suyRd/

Comment: The HTML should not be changed in the fiddle